# why this java equals method violates consistency rule

Tags: java

One of the following example codes is a wrong implementation of java equals method. It violated the consistency rule. Which one violated the rule and please points out where and how in the method it violated the consistency rule?

example 1

```
public class WrongEquals {

private final AtomicInteger counter;

public WrongEquals(int start) {
    this.counter = new AtomicInteger(start);
}

public int getCount() {
    return counter.getAndDecrement();
}

@override public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }   
    WrongEquals that = (WrongEquals) o;
    return counter.get() == that.getCount();
}

@override public int hashCode() {
    return counter.hashCode();
}
}
```

exmaple 2

```
public class WrongEquals {

    private final AtomicInteger counter;

    public WrongEquals(int start) {
            this.counter = new AtomicInteger(start);
    }

    public int getCount() {
            return counter.getAndDecrement();
    }

    @override public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                    return true;
            }
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
                    return false;
            }
            WrongEquals that = (WrongEquals) o;
            return getCount() == that.getCount();   //changed here
    }

    @override public int hashCode() {
            return counter.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one do you think it is and why do you think so?

Comment: This stinks of homework. Not that questions about homework are necessarily bad, but you've literally just pasted your homework here and shown no effort. Please follow up on what @SotiriosDelimanolis asked for. Also, what is "the consistency rule"???

Comment: Aside from the fact that one violates consistency, it's not a good idea to calculate hashcode and equality based on mutable state.

Comment: Although it's HW here's a hint: read [the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and pay special attention to the "consistent" part.

Answer (score 2):

you should have learned about the many properties that should be satisfied when creating equals methods. They are  reflexive, symmetric,transitive and consistent. google has more details if you need it.

Given these properties try writing some code that will test them out on each class and see which ones fail. This should be fairly easy since you already have the code for the classes.